# .less file not complied in .css file in magneto2

Tags: magento2, less-css, less-compilation

File Path In App Folder

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/local-l.less

File Path Must Be In Pub Folder

> /pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/css/local-l.min.css

But local-l.min.css Not Generating In Pub Folder.

Also Error showing on browser

> (index):1 Refused to apply style from 'local-l.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your local-l.less to the main styles.less file that you have. You can add it in there as an import :) I am using SASS no i can't tell you the exact syntax but if you google less import you should be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks, I found solution. I have an syntax error.  I resolved it